# leetcode Compile Error :conflicting types for 'xxx'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am a newbie in leetcode platform.I got a `Compile Error` when I submitted my solution.
The error is about my custom function, but I have run the code in codeblocks successfully.Who can tell me why?

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char* s) {

    int longestSub = 1;

    for(int startIndex = 0, step = 1; startIndex + step < strlen(s); ){

        if(myNoRepeating(s+startIndex, step, s[startIndex+step])){
            step++;
            longestSub = step;
        } else {
            startIndex++;
        }

    }

    return longestSub;
}

int myNoRepeating(char *substring, int length, char next){
    for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++){
        if(substring[length-1] == substring[i])
            return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(next == substring[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

> Run Code Status: Compile Error
>
> Run Code Result: Line 19: conflicting
>   types for 'myNoRepeating'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function prototype before calling.

```
int myNoRepeating(char *substring, int length, char next);
```

Put this statement before `lengthOfLongestSubstring` method to resolve the compile error.

Another solution is to reorder the code like:

```
   int myNoRepeating(char *substring, int length, char next){
    for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++){
        if(substring[length-1] == substring[i])
            return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(next == substring[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char* s) {

    int longestSub = 1;

    for(int startIndex = 0, step = 1; startIndex + step < strlen(s); ){

        if(myNoRepeating(s+startIndex, step, s[startIndex+step])){
            step++;
            longestSub = step;
        } else {
            startIndex++;
        }

    }

    return longestSub;
}
```